# How to use GPU parallel computing to accelarate the for loop?

Tags: for-loop, julia, gpu, cpu

I am a fresh person on Julia, my question is: there is a piece of code that contains a large matrix. The matrix elements are calculated by nesting four for loops. Now I want to accelerate the calculation. How can I achieve acceleration through GPU?

I've tried the CUDA.jl(Base.Threads) to accelerate the calculation by GPU(CPU) but it was failed to work. The main problem is I do not know how to write the correct code with using these tool.
the code can be simplified as following shows:

```
m=n=4000
Gamma=zeros(3*n,(m+1)*n)
#f1_int(q),g1_int(q),h1_int(q) are different functions which includes integrals.
for l in 0:2:m                                        
        for q in 0:1:m                                                  
            for i in 1:n                                 
                for j in 1:n                              
                    if  l ==lprime
                        result = f1_int(q)
                        Gamma[l*n+i,q*n+j]=result
                    elseif l== lprime-2
                        result = h1_int(q)
                        Gamma[l*n+i,q*n+j]=result
                    elseif l ==lprime+2
                        result = g1_int(q)
                        Gamma[l*n+i,q*n+j]=result
                    else
                        result = 0
                        Gamma[l*n+i,q*n+j]=result
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return Gamma
end
```

Comment: You should show what you have attempted. SO is not a code-writing service, but we are more than willing to help diagnose your attempts. See this page for the different supported parallel computing types for julia: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/parallel-computing/